# git bisect and finding last good commit - am I missing something?

Tags: git, git-bisect

My question concerns when git bisect has found the *first bad commit*:

```
$ git bisect good
2060c40f6c3d3c057f9fdab31643599da375296b is the first bad commit  ❌
commit 2060c40f6c3d3c057f9fdab31643599da375296b
Author: ....
Date:   Tue Feb 16 11:15:52 2021 -0800
```

Now, ideally I want to proceed and identify the **LAST GOOD COMMIT**.

#### My question is:

(note:  the steps of how I found the last good commit, manually, follow.  It's not hard just tedious).

git fully knows `2060c40f6c3d3c057f9fdab31643599da375296b` was preceded by `8993de6cc8bac3d5867e6b84fe30c52c9e604737` (see below).  Is there a way to get that information quickly from git/ git bisect **when it identifies the first bad commit**, without having to search through commit history manually?

What I'd like to see

```
$ git bisect good
2060c40f6c3d3c057f9fdab31643599da375296b is the first bad commit
8993de6cc8bac3d5867e6b84fe30c52c9e604737 is the last good commit  MOCKUP
```

#### The details of how I found the last good commit:

`git checkout <mybranch-before-git-bisect>` then

`git log`

I am back all the way to the top, and can now look for the **first bad commit**

`/2060c40f6c3d3c057f9fdab31643599da375296b`

which gets me

```
commit 2060c40f6c3d3c057f9fdab31643599da375296b (037.secure.010.varsettings2jsontag, refs/bisect/bad) 
❌ 1ST BAD COMMIT
Author: ...
Date:   Tue Feb 16 11:15:52 2021 -0800

    037.secure.010.varsettings2jsontag fixed, added cssremovefilter ing for tests

commit 8993de6cc8bac3d5867e6b84fe30c52c9e604737 (refs/bisect/good-8993de6cc8bac3d5867e6b84fe30c52c9e604737)  
✅ LAST GOOD COMMIT
Author: ...
Date:   Mon Feb 15 22:29:42 2021 -0800
```

#### What doesn't work (but feels like it should)

- `git log` right after bisect found the first bad commit wasn't useful

```
$ git log
commit 27f31fc8be6c6ef0ae493272364397c7b27f2550 (HEAD -> 059.ora.010.batch_usergroup_hang)
Author: ...
Date:   Tue Feb 9 21:36:43 2021 -0800 1️⃣

    "just a backup, use it sparingly on main codelines"

commit cdd80520ffd025a98629f3aa43a817ee4ebe96ab
Author: ...
Date:   Tue Jan 26 15:41:52 2021 -0800 2️⃣

    wip on generated/urls.py - not much so far

commit b7d05cf0df9a43b8ab3f36a81e618c8130905d87
Author: ...
Date:   Sun Nov 15 22:17:12 2020 -0800 3️⃣
```

i.e. if I `git log` after git bisect finds the first bad commit, I get 3 entries widely separated in time at 1️⃣ 2️⃣ 3️⃣.  Numerous commits are missing, so this is useless.

#### I am on git version 2.23.0

Comment: You can probably just use `2060c40f6c^` to refer to last good commit (being the parent of the first bad commit). No need for `bisect` to do anything special.

Comment: @chepner I'll take that as an answer, esp if you put that as `git show 2060c40f6c^ | head -1` which resolves to showing me the commit hash for its parent too.  I know this must be obvious to anyone who knows git well, but... that's most assuredly not me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last good commit is just the parent of the first bad commit, which you can find by appending a `^` to the given commit hash:

```
$ git show 2060c40f6c^ | head -1
```